# undefined reference to `__imp_socket'

Tags: c++11, winsock2

I'm doing a socket project on win10, and I get these errors.

```
g++ -ggdb -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -o calcserver CalcServer.c 
DieWithError.c HandleTCPClient.c CalcFramer.cpp CalcParser.cpp
C:\Users\HARRYS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cceLC8Xb.o: In function `main':
D:\src/CalcServer.c:35: undefined reference to `__imp_socket'
D:\src/CalcServer.c:41: undefined reference to `__imp_htonl'
D:\src/CalcServer.c:42: undefined reference to `__imp_htons'
D:\src/CalcServer.c:45: undefined reference to `__imp_bind'
D:\src/CalcServer.c:49: undefined reference to `__imp_listen'
D:\src/CalcServer.c:58: undefined reference to `__imp_accept'
D:\src/CalcServer.c:64: undefined reference to `__imp_inet_ntoa'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [calcserver] Error 1
```

I tried to link *Ws2_32.lib*. I download *Ws2_32.lib* under directory *src*, and modify my makefile like this:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-ggdb -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic

LINKFLAGS = -L"D:\src" -lWS2_32

H_FILES=CalcFramer.hpp CalcParser.hpp
FILES=CalcServer.c DieWithError.c HandleTCPClient.c CalcFramer.cpp CalcParser.cpp

all: calcserver

calcserver: $(FILES) $(H_FILES)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o calcserver $(FILES)

clean:
rm -rf calcserver
```

However, I still get the above errors. I've already changed all the *sys/socket.h* headers to *Winsock.h* and *Winsock2.h*. So I think it's not that part that leads me to the errors.